# How can I force TFS to let me download a folder (other than methods listed)?

Tags: visual-studio-2010, tfs

I have a seemingly common problem, but cannot find a common solution that will work for me. I recently had my computer re-imaged and am now in the process of redownloading a solution from TFS. One of the solution folders contains 2 folders that list "Not downloaded" in the "Latest" column of the Source Control Explorer. When trying to open the solution, I get the error "The project file could not be loaded. Could not find file x". I've tried the methods listed below, to no avail:

1. Get Specific Version, checking Overwrite options
2. Deleting, .suo file, restarting VS2010
3. tf get /force
4. Remove mapping, deleting local files, remapping entire TFS project to local folder
5. tfpt rollback /changeset where the last changeset for the .csproj listed a branch and a merge as pending changes by me
6. File -> Source Control -> Open from Source Control, Navigate to TFS project, try to open .csproj in undownloaded folder, receive error "The selected file cannot be opened. The project file has been moved, renamed or is not on your computer."

I may be missing other things I've tried, I'll be sure to update this list if I can think of anything.

Besides those listed above, is there any other way to get those 2 folders and their content from TFS?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the problem. I recently added a certain domain group to the TFSProject/Readers TFS group, then explicitly denied access to all rights in those two folders. It seems that although I am in the Contributor TFS group, I'm also a "Reader", so I denied access to myself.

Answer (score 6):

Try browsing via visual studio command line to the directory and do a:

```
tf get . /force /recursive
```

This should forcibly recurse down from the current directory.

Comment: Tried this, but it looks like it only "gets" the files and folders that I currently have from the solution on my local drive, not those 2 project folders which are listed in Source Control Explorer listed as "Not Downloaded"

Answer (score 0):

You have tried most of the things that I would suggest. A force-get-latest should work if it's a simple case of TFS being confused about what is on your pc.

Are the "folders" in tfs, or in your solution explorer? Folders in the solution explorer typically mirror the real disk structure, but it is possible to get files and folders in a different location in the SE than on disk. This coild mean that the files the solution explorer is referencing are not mapped into your tfs workspace.

I would check the workspace mapping is as simple as possible (no branches or extra unneeded folders etc), close the solution, force-get the latest version of the disk structure from the source control view, and then load the .csproj file in a text editor to check exactly what the project is referencing to be sure that all the files exist and are in sensible places on disk.